# IBM x3550 M4 (7914) CPU upgrade to v2 Xeon?

Tags: ibm, xeon

IBM released the x3550 M4 originally with the v1 E5-2600 CPUs; later on, when v2 was announced they did the refresh and started telling them with v2 CPUs.

Can I just order two v2 CPUs for my existing, originally-v1 M4?

Comment: Out of topic, it's a question for a reseller. Call IBM or get the HMM for your server, and check spare part, if it's listed then yes, if it's not listed, then no. (HMM (hardware maintenance manual))) I tell the term, as you can easilly search the term HMM and it will be list.

Comment: Dig to the firmware upgrades for your particular machine on the IBM support site and look what processors are supported. Very easy lookup task, the main difficulty lies in finding the relefant page on IBM's site.

Comment: @yagmoth555 "out of topic", "out of topic", blahblah. someone might know, so next time just don't comment if that's all you can add to the conversation, thanks!

Comment: I answered you in my comment, check the HMM and call the vendor, as anyway you have to call the vendor to get the piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking to IBM Sales: yes, I can. You need to upgrade UEFI and the firmware first, after that it will work.

Limitations include however:

- 1333 MHz memories are not supported anymore
- no support for 4Gb FC anymore
- The Emulex dual port 10GbE support is gone

Answer (score 0):

As my previous advice. Please see the images.

[image]

[image]